# Can't get access to a disk for compression - UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, permissions, user-permissions, file-security, access-rules

I need compact all the folders of my E:\ But when i try with this code, i get this access exception.
I'm new on programming and are trying learn how a i can do this work.
I'm using the dotnetzip for compact the directories inside E:.
Some parts of the code are just copied, i know that... but i'm trying learn how to do work.

I already tried some others solution for solve the problem answered here.
Like add a manifest to the project who requeireAdministrator permissions to run and insert a Access Control Rule to modify the security of E:\ Something that i notice when do this is my user have permissions removed from the subfiles and directories of E:\ But without this access rule the same exception keep existing.

```
        try
        {

            ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
            zip.AddDirectory(@"E:\");
            zip.Save(@"C:\Users\vitorbento\Desktop\backup.zip");

            Console.WriteLine("Compactação concluída");
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            FileAttributes attr = (new FileInfo(DirectPath)).Attributes;
            Console.Write("UnAuthorizedAccessException: Unable to access file. ");
            if ((attr & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) > 0)
            Console.Write("The file is read-only.");
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried explicitly running this as an administrator?

Comment: yeah, my visual studio are running as administrator and i tried with the right click to

Comment: Do you have a hidden 'E:\System Volume Information' folder? By default even Administrator does not have access to that. Perhaps you will have to build your zip file more manually, enumerating the directories you have access to, and adding them?

Comment: yes, I can do this way, adding manually, for me also is the volume information folder who give me the error but this program will run in some differents computers and i cant imagine what directories will be in there, one way what i think is adding a exclusion for the System Volume folder, but i cant find a way to do this